# Multiple Java ActionListeners

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

So what I have been trying to do for past month is set multiple action listeners for my buttons without succes. I have 3 buttons, and i want them to print some text on text area depending which button is pressed. So could somebody tell me where exactly do I have to write those listeners? Thanks in advance.

```
public class Lotto  {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Color color1 = new Color(250,250,250);
    Color color2 = new Color(200,200,200);
    Color color3 = new Color(255,66,66);

    JFrame f1 = new JFrame(); 

    f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    f1.setSize(400,400);
    f1.setVisible(true);
    f1.setLayout(null);
    f1.setResizable(false);

    JButton start = new JButton("Start");
    start.setBounds(25,325,100,25);
    f1.add(start);

    JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
    stop.setBounds(150,325,100,25);
    f1.add(stop);

    JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
    exit.setBounds(275,325,100,25);
    f1.add(exit);

    JTextArea ta1 = new JTextArea("Your inputs");
    ta1.setEditable(false);
    ta1.setBounds(25,125,350,50);
    ta1.setBackground(color2);
    f1.add(ta1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't show  us any of your attempts on writing a listener, so there's no way we can guess what you're doing wrong. The best we can do is to suggest that you read the tutorials. Also, I suggest that you don't have any of the code that you show above in a main method but instead have it in OOP-land, perhaps in a class's constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to give [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) tutorial from Oracle a look.

Answer (score 3):

**Q: What have you tried?

A: I didn't.**

---

Anyway, [`AbstractButton.addActionListener`](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs7/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29) is what you're looking for. Either construct a separate `ActionListener` for each `JButton` instance, or construct a single `ActionListener` that every `JButton` instance will use. With regard to the latter, use [`EventObject.getSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) to determine which component fired the event.